# When Google App Engine is free?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am developing a a small dictionary app (in Go) that is not likely to get much traffic. Maybe 100 unique visitors per day and each visitor makes 10 queries. Also the app files are very slim. Not more than 100MB altogether. 
I've looked at the [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) but it is really confusing. For example I don't know what to put at CPU and Memories per hour.

On their '[flexible scheme](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2017-q1-cloud-emea-gcp-bkws-freetrial&gclid=CjwKEAjw9_jJBRCXycSarr3csWcSJABthk07fo7DodnzDrn7elbDxB2idE2igr8Kwgo2RbCnXUazlxoCJ-rw_wcB&dclid=CNH_8JuGuNQCFdaLUQodbJoAKg#id=b5df2d04-0f5d-4e58-9c67-f3e21628e301)' I tried what seemed to be very low specs: 1 CPU, 128MB memory and 100MB disk space and it turned out to be 
**$39.05 per month**!

Also on '[Standard scheme](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/)' the  most basic instance is B1 which costs $0.05 per hour, amonts to **$36 per month**!

It is ridiculously expensive for lean VPS. So where is the GAE free tire? Am I missing something here? How do you estimate the price that I should expect?

Answer (score 3):

Google most of product comes with free quotas. [Here is list of all products](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits) which gives free quotas to test your webapp.

I am currently using Google compute engine and Google Cloud storage without paying anything to Google. Also Google gives $300 credit to new customer who enable billing on their accounts.

I still have same credits because 1 f1 micro instance for compute engine is totally free, and that is enough for my small app. I am not using app engine but here is free quota list for that as well.

> 28 instance hours per day
>
> 5 GB Cloud Storage
>
> 1 GB of egress per day
>
> Shared memcache
>
> 1000 search operations per day, 10 MB search indexing
>
> 100 emails per day

[But now Google charges standard rate from 9th march 2017](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#always-free)

> Please also note that any usage prior to March 9, 2017 for the above
> listed services will be billed at the standard rates. Customers who
> have exceeded their Always Free monthly usage limits for any service
> prior to March 9, 2017 will not be eligible for Always Free usage
> until April 1, 2017.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all these cloud jargon. What does `28 instance hours per day` mean in http req/res terms?

Comment: If your app is developed under python it means it required x number of instance (to load python program, codes execution, http request, API request etc) for that. You can say instance means process. Google charges instance based on minutes, so if you think in night you've small traffic then you can minimize the number of instance, so you can save some money  [Here is good reference for instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed)

Comment: @Goyllo instance is an duplicate of the application.

Comment: What's the free quota for traffic?

Comment: I found, here are listed all free quotas  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests